# Red Hat + pip + virtualenv + proxy = Error

Tags: redhat, proxy, virtualenv, pip

i've an issue: my corporate proxy kill every pip-installation.
`export http_proxy=` doesn't works: 
`Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))`

And `pip install --proxy=... --trusted-host=...` doesn't works too.
Only if i use it together i can install somything from `pip`.

And it's in OS.
When i use `virtualenv` it doesn't works even together. And i don't know, what to do. Please, help me.

Example,
`sudo pip install --proxy=... --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org sentry`

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /packages/bb/ee/edda27f5f59a98adb2aa1c0c939d7a15cada155eea73f5b56dc0b593deaa/sentry-9.0.0-py27-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/bb/ee/edda27f5f59a98adb2aa1c0c939d7a15cada155eea73f5b56dc0b593deaa/sentry-9.0.0-py27-none-any.whl (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",))
```

Comment: Hi, it's a bit unclear what you ask here. Could you read https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question? Mainly by defining "does not work" and separating your expectations, your observations and goals would be a big help.

Comment: @asdmin update.

Answer (score 2):

Your corporate proxy requires a username and password to be provided, but your `http_proxy` environment variable doesn't have them.

The `http_proxy` must be set with the username and password, for example:

```
http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080/
```

Comment: sorry, but i know about it. And i write it `--proxy=...` Of cource i don't write actual host:port or my password...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple things happening concurrently:

1. The error `error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)` indicates that you need authentication to use the proxy as explained by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/954891/37681).
2. In addition to setting an environment variable `http_proxy=` you typically also need `https_proxy=` to instruct applications to use the proxy server for https connections.
3. When executing commands with `sudo` the environment will be sanitized and most likely the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables won't be available for the pip command.
   You can include a line such as `Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"` at the start of `/etc/sudoers` to keep those user supplied environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

My corporate proxy works so bad/unexpected way - it downloads to middle-server, and than gives me download.
So, for terminal user (my computer) it looks like downloads aaborted. And it ruins with exeption `ReadTimeoutError`

So, i increase timeout and wait - and it installs as it needs.